# How to save a parent key on hibernate self-reference query in grails

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, grails

I don't know how to reference the parent key of the parent id to the foreign key of child

example is

the parent row id : 4028943347c2ddfc0147c30aa415000a

when I reference it on the child class no results found because the foreign key has this: nodeproject.Node : 4028943347c2ddfc0147c30aa415000a I don't know how to get the actual foreign key on my database. Thanks!

```
class Node {

String id
String description
String parentName

static constraints = {
    id(nullable: true, maxSize: 32)
    parentName(nullable: true)
    description(maxSize: 100)
}

static transients = ['allCriteria']

static hasMany =[children: Node]
static belongsTo = [parent: Node]

static mapping = {
    cache true
    id generator: 'uuid'
    table 'samp_node'
    version false
}
}
```

The error shows that my parent key is null even I instantiated it.

```
    class NodeTests extends GroovyTestCase {



    void testPersistParentAndChildNode(){
    Node node = new Node(description: 'Parent A', parentName: '1')
    Node child = new Node(description:  'Child', parentName: 'a')
    Node child2 = new Node(description: 'Child', parentName: 'b')
    child.setParent(node)
    child2.setParent(node)
    node.getChildren().add(child) //line 15
    node.getChildren().add(child2)

   }
   }
```

This is my Test Case but the error is:

```
    Cannot invoke method add() on null object
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method add() on null object
    at nodeproject.NodeTests.testPersistParentAndChildNode(NodeTests.groovy:15)
```

Comment: Why you are used static hasMany =[subNode: Node]
    static belongsTo = [criteria: Node] 
with in the class Node 
Association is usually happens between different classes.

Comment: It is because I am doing it for only 1 table, and this is for making the criteria stored in database example
1. Main Idea >
   1.1 Sub Main Idea
     >> 1.1.a Sub sub main idea

just like that